# Codeigniter: getting errors when I load Session library

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I get the following errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: chmod() has been disabled for security reasons
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 191
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/almsa/public_html/library/application/controllers/Home.php
>   Line: 23 Function: library
>
> File: /home/almsa/public_html/library/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

But if I remove $this->load->library('session'); from my controller then the errors go. 
My controller has only that line.

the controller works fine on localhost but gets that error when I uploaded it to a live server.

Please help, Thank you !

Comment: Remove the chmod string from the disable_functions at php.ini* file

Comment: Or you can Ask your hosting provider to remove the string above if you don't have an access to the php.ini* file

Comment: Please try setting the Error Reporting in the site Global Configuration to System Default or to None, that should hide PHP Notices and Warnings. But it is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the chmod string from the disable_functions at **php.ini*** file
- Ask your hosting provider to remove the string above if you don't
  have an access to the **php.ini*** file
- Change hosting provider which allows the running of the chmod
  function.

Reference: http://www.2by2host.com/articles/php-errors-faq/disabled_chmod/

Comment: What a coincidence, I am about to give the same answer.  @dhruv jadia

Comment: yes, sir but I just did the comment it.  no problem. solving a problem is the main part. Hope we did that.

Comment: Thank you both, please let me know if I can find the php.ini myself or should I talk to the server support team? I use Cpanel.

Comment: tell me hosting site?

Comment: seems I have no php.ini, according to http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/update-local-php-settings

Comment: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9417/2219/how-to-change-php-version-on-shared-servers'

Comment: I don't need to change php's version but I need to access to php.ini and seems I cannot

Answer (score 1):

Add to your controller the following constructor:

```
function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('session');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its still not running on live you need to check you config settings regarding sessions storage in **CI 3**

```
    $config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;   // Mainly check this item `sess_save_path`
    $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
    $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```